# Ruby Sockets finding sent and received time for messages

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcp, udp

Is there a predefined function for the socket classes in ruby that will allow me to record the time messages are sent and received?

At the moment I am sending or receiveing the message, and then recording the time immediately afterwards. While this is working I was wondering if anyone knew a better method?

Here is how i do it at the moment. This is based off a ClientTCP class i had to write. The servers are laid out in a similar manner.

```
def send_mess
    @n.times do
        @client.print(@message)
        @sent_time_arr << (Time.now.to_f)

        sleep(1/@freq)

    end
    @client.close
    return @sent_time_arr
end
```

Any help you could provide would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but there is no way to do this with the standard socket library. You could try to override the `read()` and `write()` methods on the socket class, but what you are doing now seems to be working as well.